# Cannot resolve symbol 'RequiresApi', Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I can not import `RequiresApi`.

Error:

```
Import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi; - (Can not resolve symbol 'RequiresApi')
```

Used in the Android Image Cropper project, part of the code:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
        public void start(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull android.app.Fragment fragment) {
            fragment.startActivityForResult(getIntent(context), CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

minSdkVersion 17

my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 18
        versionName "1.998"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar')
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```

Comment: please add youR gradle file...

Comment: @Opiatefuchs i add

Comment: I guess you missed a few steps. Follow the api to use support annotations: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely due to the lack of the annotations dependency.

Add to your `build.gradle` and sync:

```
dependencies {
   implementation("androidx.annotation:annotation:1.7.1")
}
```